# Shared use of NTFS HDD with Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, ntfs

I have been using a desktop computer setup with Ubuntu and Windows 7 on separate SSD's and both operating systems using the same NTFS formatted HDD for data storage. I recently added Windows 10 to the setup. After having used the HDD with Windows 10, Ubuntu's apps can no longer write to it. The error messages say that the storage device is read-only. Does Windows 10, when using a device or its partition, make settings to it that restrict access to users or other operating systems, and if so, can such settings be changed? Or should such a setting be changed in Ubuntu to make the device writable again?

Comment: Before starting Ubuntu, did you shutdown Windows completely or it it just hibernated?

Comment: I shut down Windows completely before starting Ubuntu. Or does Windows not shut down when you select shut down, instead of sleep? As a test, I formatted a USB flash drive with the FAT files system, and it works without problems in both systems. So the issue must be specific to NTFS- or it might have to do with the HDD being a SATA drive. The only explanation is that Windows is writing something to the drive that messes up shared use with Linux.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/q/145902/271

Comment: The problem has been resolved. It was caused by the fast startup of Windows 10, which by default is activated, and it was fixed by deactivating fast startup. So Windows wasn't writing anything undesired on the HDD; it simply wouldn't let go of it.

Comment: @Vaedderen please write a self-answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the fast startup function of Windows which hibernates the OS instead of shutting it down completely when shut down by the user. The problem was fixed by disabling fast startup in the Power Settings of Windows.